# Are the social sciences amenable to the idea of making money off their research?

Tags: collaboration, industry, academic-freedom

I realize that lots of engineering/biology/physics/computing sciences tend to encourage their researchers to go and make industrial applications out of their research.

I noticed there is a complete lack of that in the social sciences (which is neither bad nor good), except in economics. I never hear of sociologists/anthropologists/ethnographers/etc. making a business out of their work and research.

How come? Why are those disciples less prone to industrialize their work compared to STEM fields? Is it a cultural byproduct of the mode of work in those fields?

Comment: Actually, most mathematicians and computer scientists don't make a business out of their research either. Likely the same is true of those in other STEM fields.

Comment: What do you mean, "cultural byproduct of the mode of work in those fields"?

Comment: @Azor Ahai - I imagine the history of research and epistemology in these fields influence whether or not sociology/anthropology researchers go into industry.

Comment: @Buffy that is very true - however there seem to be more mathematicians and computer scientists that go into industry then those in the social sciences.

Comment: Actually, I guess not. But they are probably managing the geeks instead. History majors often wind up in management.

Comment: Note that titles should ideally be questions (with a question mark), or at least give an indication of what the specific problem is. We discourage titles like "retaking a course" since someone with the same situation in future will be unlikely to find the post (and because posts with such titles typically don't contain a well-defined question at all, but that does not seem to be the case here). I've moved your first paragraph to the title; you can make further edits if needed.

Comment: More substantively: can you give an example of a social science concept that could be "industrialized" but hasn't been? Otherwise, this reduces to the trivial answer.

Comment: @cag51 thank you for the heads-up.  One concept could be analysis of anomie. Imagine some company wants to "peter principle" some valued worker(s) but doesn't consider the impact of anomie by uprooting a worker from their department which they may or may not have had most of their professional career at. Studying the impacts of this companies' potential choice and reporting how to mitigate (or even cancel) the effects of switching (if even considered a good idea at all) could help to reduce company loss of efficiency in workers improperly promoted or moved

Comment: Not sure I'm convinced by the example. A consulting firm based in social science and staffed by social scientists aware of "anomie" may be a good idea, but I suspect that market forces -- not some unwritten rule of academic culture -- is the limiting factor in commercializing such a concept.

Answer (score 3):

I think one piece of the equation is that some of the [natural sciences (rather than social sciences)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branches_of_science) study much finer-grained phenomena. Relevant XKCD:

[image: XKCD 435]

By this, I mean, it's easy to monetize, shall we say, more efficient combustion, the new best encryption algorithm, or the cure for cancer. What a social scientist might study are human systems at the level of communities.

We can learn that large segments of the population are obese because fast food is cheaper than healthy food in their [environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_desert), but you don't solve that by becoming a grocery store entrepreneur, you solve that by going into government.

It's hard to sell the solution to systemic racism.

Comment: +1. I was considering an answer based on the counter-example of [Duolingo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duolingo), which indeed was successfully commercialized (out of CMU). But I think this is a special case of what you say: things that can be commercialized, are, but most things in social science cannot.

Comment: @cag51 Yes, as a linguist, I have a lot more to say about the "classification" of linguistics as a science, but suffice it to say it doesn't fit neatly between, say, "Sociologists" and "Psychologists" in the XKCD spectrum. That said, I'd point out the founders of Duolingo were computer scientists with no training in linguistics (at least according to their WPs).

Comment: And, I would say, Duolingo is not especially innovative, linguistically.

Comment: If we count Duolingo, there are plenty of startups offering non-STEM education and other services (does DeepL count, too?). And that is not to count all the predatory practices of Dr. Charlatan selling these personal growth courses which are definitely founded in modern psychology and social science, or someone offering to pick the best career for you based on your genealogy or... Well, you get the idea. The only way this can exist ethically and outside of educational settings is governments being the main contractee, IMHO.

Comment: @Lodinn Well, *I* didn't count Duolingo, but machine translation would be a much better counterexample. Not really sure where the Dr. Charlatan stuff comes in ...

Comment: I always found that comic personally funny because the sociologist is minding their business. I do imagine that large corporations/governments would want concrete ideas on how to "fix systemic racism" - even if piece by piece. I never bought into the idea personally that sociology couldn't make it on the market because it tells the powers that be what they don't want to hear (if so a huge chunk of economists would be out of work also)

Comment: @wonderinghuh "*I do imagine that large corporations/governments would want concrete ideas on how to "fix systemic racism".*" Well, wouldn't that be great ...

Comment: I should clarify "some" in some certain contexts.
One thing that also convinces me that sociologists/anthropologists should and have to get involved somehow in society (that doesn't purely concern the government) is that economics always seems to be able to sell itself as a social science catchall, even in circumstances that don't necessarily need that field. I don't buy that economists are purely the mouthpiece of certain economic actors, but moreso ignorance on certain people's part. I mean, most people can tell you what economists do, but can they say the same for sociology/anthropology?

Comment: @wonderinghuh Not sure what "some" you are clarifying, as that is the first mention in the Q or my A.

Comment: I mean "some" in context of some large corporations/governments would want concrete ideas on how to "fix systemic racism. Apologize for the confusion.

Comment: @wonderinghuh I am speaking in broad strokes here.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this largely has to do with the initial funding boost provided by a variety of means - or lack thereof.

If some research has potential applications in the industry, governments and private organizations both would be willing to bridge this gap, invest in bringing academic results to the wider public. It is rarely academics who make the first move - after all, if one's goal was to make money off their research, academia is hardly the place to be. It is true there are spin-offs with ties to academia, but more often than not, people branch out very early in their careers.

And as for ethnographers at least, they are encouraged to make their results more accessible as well, but it is not what you would necessarily encounter in the wild. What is the business model here? A museum might pay them to make their expositions better (and they do), they could start a youtube channel or be featured on one (again, some do), but in general, business models are rather limited there.

In addition to that, commercializing sociology or anthropology is very dangerous: whoever has the money to pay steering the society is widely seen as an already existing problem, there is no need to further exacerbate it. Not to say it does not happen already, sociology is heavily involved in politics, and sociologists are being featured on political programs (and, I am sure, are mostly well-reimbursed for it). For an academic researcher in STEM, the notion of public service would not necessarily conflict with running a startup. For a sociologist, it most likely will.

Another evidence of this is biomedical research: the field is heavily commercialized, and "undesirable" research outcomes are getting suppressed as a result. If the same were to happen in social sciences, there would be no freedom of research and academic honesty, whoever pays for the show would immediately use this newly acquired academic credibility to push their own agenda.

Comment: " For an academic researcher in STEM, the notion of public service would not necessarily conflict with running a startup. For a sociologist, it most likely will" Could you expand on this? I can think of some instances that the notion of public service could conflict in running a startup.

But to even address that point - can a start-up be always self-serving? Couldn't you have a startup that also addresses and lessens social ills?

Comment: If a startup is unable to support itself and aims at lessening social ills, it is called a charity, this is obviously possible. Tech startups aim at providing some service with either a nontrivial amount of customers or a few very rich ones willing to pay for it, at least in theory. Perhaps I lack imagination, but I can not readily imagine a scenario where someone having money would seek profit from investing it in a social science startup and this would somehow not end up with social problems being more pronounced. Rich getting richer, that kind of thing.

Comment: Caveat: if a public charity such as USDR (https://www.usdigitalresponse.org/about) fits your understanding of a startup, they very much do exist, but typically are not interested in doing novel research at all. So for a practicing academic it makes more sense to stay within the university and be employed by such charities only on occasion.

Comment: The way I imagine it - it would be a company of social scientists researching pressing problems and open sourcing their work - the catch is they also sell their services to companies/governments who want their services to improve their product/governance. Think of the Red Hat model - FOSS but also sells services to companies who can't or won't do the social science research needed.

Comment: @wonderinghuh Those are called "think tanks."

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- thanks! I have a wayyy easier time conceptualizing the idea.